# How can I set rest of width to a right float element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

All I'm trying to do is setting `width: {the rest of width}` to an element which has `float:right` property. Here is my code:

```css
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.fix{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 80px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.rest{
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='fix'> fix width </div>
    <div class='rest'> it should has both right float and the rest of width</div>
</div>
```

How can I fill that gap? This is expected output:

[image]

Comment: You can put `width: calc(100% - 80px)` on `.rest`

Comment: this seems like a PERFECT time to use `flexbox` (also pretty much has all browser support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how flexible you are on the CSS but if you use `float:left` on the fixed div you can use `overflow:auto` on the right one.

```css
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.fix{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 80px;
  display:inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.rest{
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='fix'> fix width </div>
    <div class='rest'> it should has both right float and the rest of width</div>
</div>
```

If you need to float the actual content of the right div then still to the right, you could add a content container to float right within.

```css
.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.fix{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 80px;
  display:inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.rest{
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.right-content{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='fix'> fix width </div>
    <div class='rest'><div class="right-content"> it should has both right float and the rest of width</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `calc` to subtract the value.

```
.rest{
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}
```

Comment: You know, the most of my website's users use old browsers and their browser doesn't support `clac()`. Isn't there any workaround?

Comment: Not without Javascript, here's the current compatibility chart: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Answer (score 0):

Apply width in %

```
.fix{ 
      border: 1px solid blue;     
      width: 20%;     
      display:inline-block;    
      float:left;
}
 .rest{ 
      float: right; 
      border: 1px solid red; 
      width:80%; 
}
```